# Sites page on AEM not opening after service pack installation?

Tags: aem

I had AEM 6.5 already set up. I uploaded the service pack 4 on CRX and after that I am not able to open the sites page or see the workflows and many other things. Though i am still able to open up crx and system/console. What could be the issue for sites not opening up?

Link to logs:
https://github.com/gauti0715/AEM/blob/master/stackoverflow-question-sites

Comment: Hi, you would need to provide more info, like messages in the error.log, are all the bundles active? And so on. It could be many things.

Comment: @ronnyfm I have provided the link to logs. These logs are just after the AEM instance is up and running.

Comment: I see some errors related to ACS Commons, try using the latest version. 

08.07.2020 11:01:29.808 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1594186284075] GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver Calling the error handler resulted in an error

Next time, you can only post the specific ERRORs shown in the file instead of posting the whole log (because you could leak sensitive information related to your project)

Comment: Thanks @ronnyfm. I saw that ACS Commons bundle had a error. So i again restarted the AEM instance , clearing the previous quickstart folder, and uploaded my service pack again. Now it works.